# Does "iterate" change the meaning of the applied function?

Tags: haskell, lambda, loops

When I put the following lambda expression in `ghci` I get `1`:

```
ghci> (\x -> x+1) 0
1
```

But when I use that function with `iterate` I get

```
ghci> take 10 (iterate (\x -> x+1) 0)
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

I expected to get a list equal to `[1..10]`. Why not?

Comment: One of the nice things about haddock is that there's a source link next to every function. In case you're wondering how a particular function works, look it up on Hoogle and click on the source link. Ingo gave the correct answer below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first result of iterate is the original input without the function applied, i.e. the function is called 0 times.  That's why the result is one off from what you expect.

Answer (score 7):

More specifically, iterate is implemented lie this:

```
iterate f v = v : iterate f (f v)
```

Just remember that the start value you give to iterate will appear first in thelist - that's it.

Answer (score 5):

Stop...Hoogle time!

http://haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=iterate

*click `iterate`*

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:iterate

> `iterate f x` returns an infinite list of repeated applications of `f` to `x`:
>
> ```
>  iterate f x == [x, f x, f (f x), ...]
> ```

There you go. It works that way because that's how it says it works. I'm not trying to be flippant, just hoping to illustrate the usefulness of Hoogle and the docs. (Sounds like a good name for a Haskell band: "Hoogle and the Docs")